# SQL Error: <Column> not valid in the context where it is used. How to set maxColumnNameLength property in persistence file for DB2 database?

Tags: db2, openjpa

Got below issue while migrating from WAS 7 to 8.5 and DB2 from V10 to 11.5 version
Error:
`

"T0." is not valid in the context where it is used. {prepstmnt 862903867 SELECT t0., t0., t0., t0., t0., t0., t0., t0., t0., t0., t0., t0., t0., t0., t0., t0. FROM  t0 WHERE t0. = ?  optimize for 1 row} [code=-206, state=42703]SQLCA OUTPUT[Errp=SQLNQ075, Errd=-2145779603, 0, 0, 0, -500, 0]
"T0." is not valid in the context where it is used.
An error occurred during implicit system action type "2". Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-206", SQLSTATE "42703" and message tokens "T0.".
An error occurred during implicit system action type "2". Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-206", SQLSTATE "42703" and message tokens "T0.".
                    `

I am using Db2 database.

Please suggest how to set maxColumnNameLength=256 in above properties?

Answer (score 0):

You first asked: how to set property maxColumnNameLength for Db2. ("Please suggest how to set maxColumnNameLength=256 in above properties?)

Try including

`<property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="db2(maxColumnNameLength=256)"/>`

Remember that this might not resolve the real issue...which may lie elsewhere...

Check also setting this property (in case this is PM80441):

`<property name="openjpa.Compatibility" value="NonDefaultMappingAllowed=false"/>`

Ensure you are on the latest fixpack of the WAS for its version.

Comment: what could be the other issue and solution?

Comment: Depends on facts you don't mention in your question, versions, Db2-platform, the query that gets sent to Db2, any detailed error message that comes back from Db2 etc.  So if setting the maxColumnNameLength does not fix your issue then improve your question by adding a lot more facts and context.

Comment: Sorry. Added error message(Not able to add Column names "to.<ColumnName>")

Comment: As I expected, the problem lies elsewhere. Unless we can see the __actual__ SQL (including masked column-names) sent to Db2 we cannot comment from a Db2 perspective. You need to engage relevant people to study the WAS logs along with the (matching timestamp) Db2 logs - the DBA can see the actual queries.  This is not about programming, but instead it is about troubleshooting an upgrade.